# why is the TcpSendingMessageHandler or TcpOuboundGateway expecting a reply?

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration, tcpclient

The channel adapter is for one way communication.
But while using TcpSendingMessageHandler, the adapter is expecting a reply. and the following message is thrown same is the case with TcpOutboundGateway.

TcpNetConnection : Read Exception [Connection ID] Socket Exception : software caused connection abort: recv failed

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The sending adapter is not expecting a reply; it is possible, however, that the application has collaborating channel adapters (a receiving adapter that uses the same connection).

Even if there is no listener, we have to read from the socket so we can log that an unexpected reply was received. If we don't read from the socket, the peer could end up blocking when the buffers fill up.

What problem is this causing you?

This is typically only logged at DEBUG or TRACE level.